# Delete Blank Cells And Shift Up Fail

Tags: vba, excel

I've searched and tried alooot of solutions regarding this issue. But non of them worked. So im trying to attach the excel file here.

My issue is:

```
Column A
1324
12312

14
4323


12
11234
```

I want B to look like:

```
Column B
1324
12312
14
4323
12
11234
```

Looks simple. But it doesn't work since the Blank cells doesn't actually appear to blank. And I cant find a way to get rid of them. I'm attaching the excel file for your reference.

Excel File:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PDskY1GJKYhzzj905KrX988F8tTaNQSs

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will achieve your desired result, simply copy the code under your command button.

This will loop through row 1 to Last on Column A and if the cell is not blank it will pass the value to the next free row on Column B:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required
LastRowA = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
For i = 1 To LastRowA
'loop from row 1 to Last
    LastRowB = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'get the last row with data on Column B and offset by one (next empty row)
    If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" Then ' if Column A's value is not empty
        ws.Cells(LastRowB, "B").Value = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value 'pass that value to the next available row on Column B
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```